# Can't make my Enemy to randomly move in a range. Unity3D

Tags: c#, random, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence

Hi: Im working on a FPS mixed with some survival in 3D. I have an animated model that represents my enemy. I can make him move towards me if I am in range. If he gets closer enough he stops moving(and animating). Now Im trying to achieve a Wandering behaviour.

My idea goes like this: The enemy starts in the start position. He checks if the player is in range, if true then FollowPlayer() if false then MoveAround(), this means that he calculate a random position in a certain range of his actual position, Slerp to it and then move to that random position. After reaching the random position he should wait X seconds until the next move . The MoveAround() method I have is a Coroutine but I cant make it work. Here is the script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemyAI : MonoBehaviour {

public float rotationSpeed;
public float moveSpeed;
public float maxSpeed;
public float minRange;
public float maxRange;
public float moveRange;
Animator anim;
CharacterController controller;

// Use this for initialization
void Awake (){
    anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController> ();
}
void Start () {
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate () {
    FollowPlayer ();
    StartCoroutine(MoveAround ());
}
void FollowPlayer(){
    Vector3 playerPos = GameObject.Find ("Player").transform.position;
    Vector3 lookDir = playerPos - transform.position;
    Vector3 moveDir = lookDir;// * moveSpeed;
    moveDir *= Time.fixedDeltaTime;

    if((Vector3.Distance(transform.position, playerPos) <= maxRange) && (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, playerPos) > minRange) ){
        Vector3 previous = transform.position;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation (lookDir), rotationSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        controller.Move(moveDir);
        float velocity = ((transform.position - previous).magnitude) / Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    //  Debug.Log("velocidad: " + velocity);
        previous = transform.position;
        anim.SetFloat ("speed", velocity);
    }
    if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, playerPos) < minRange){
        controller.Move(Vector3.zero);
        Debug.LogWarning("hey");
        anim.SetFloat("speed",controller.velocity.magnitude);
    }
}
IEnumerator MoveAround(){
    Vector3 playerPos = GameObject.Find ("Player").transform.position;
    Vector3 randomPos = Random.onUnitSphere * moveRange;
    randomPos = new Vector3 (randomPos.x + transform.position.x, transform.position.y, randomPos.z + transform.position.z);
    Vector3 lookDir = randomPos - transform.position;
    Vector3 moveDir = lookDir;
    moveDir *= Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    Debug.Log ("Player Pos: " + playerPos);
    Debug.Log ("Random Pos: " + randomPos);
    Debug.Log ("Look Dir: " + lookDir);
    Debug.Log ("Move Dir: " + moveDir);

    if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, playerPos) > maxRange){
        Debug.Log("Moving the enemy");
        Vector3 previous = transform.position;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation (lookDir), rotationSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        controller.Move(moveDir);
        float velocity = ((transform.position - previous).magnitude) / Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    //  Debug.Log("velocidad: " + velocity);
        previous = transform.position;
        anim.SetFloat ("speed", velocity);
        Debug.Log("Enemy moved");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
        Debug.Log("waiting the first 2 seconds");
    }
    Debug.Log ("arrived at destination");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
    Debug.Log ("COroutine final");
}

void OnDrawGizmosSelected(){
    Gizmos.color = Color.green;
    Gizmos.DrawWireSphere (transform.position, maxRange);
    Gizmos.DrawWireSphere (transform.position, minRange);
}
}
```

NOTE: The map is supposed to be flat but It would be great if the code worked for a map with variable heigth. 
Im moving the char with a Character Controller is it the correct approach?

Comment: Could I see your debug log?
Add one for playerPos

Comment: Sure: The enemy is set at (50,0,50) when I hit Play. Then this is the first console log: ·Player Pos: (0.6, 0.0, 31.7) ·Random Pos: (50.5, 0.0, 48.0) ·Look Dir: (0.5, 0.0, -2.0) ·Move Dir: (0.0, 0.0, 0.0) ·Moving the enemy ·Enemy moved

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `MoveAround` and `FollowPlayer` every frame (every physics frame, actually, which is even more often). You actually want to do something more like this:

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(Move());
}

IEnumerator Move()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (nearPlayer)
            yield return StartCoroutine(FollowPlayer());
        else
            yield return StartCoroutine(MoveAround());
    }
}
```

This way you only start to move after the previous movement is finished. If you want to check positions every frame, it still works, but your checks would happen inside `MoveAround` and `FollowPlayer`. Because starting coroutines every frame totally defeats the purpose of coroutines. If you have logic that you want to run every frame (without exception), put it directly in `Update` or `FixedUpdate` without using coroutines.

Edit: To clarify, the simplest thing that's wrong with your approach is that if your coroutines take 4 seconds to run, you will have `4/Time.fixedDeltaTime` instances of each method running at any one moment, probably fighting with each other. I don't think you want 400 separate MoveAround functions running together. :)

Comment: Just have tried what you have posted but my FollowPlayer method isnt a Coroutine so should I change it to IEnumerator method? Also I have tried changing the line where it calls the FollorPlayer coroutine to: only the calling for the method itself.

Comment: Okay, first point is: You said "The enemy starts in the start position. He checks if the player is in range, if true then FollowPlayer() if false then MoveAround(),". The "Check/If/Then" logic is clearly repeated, but how often do you want it? The code I wrote assumes that both methods are coroutines and will run until they decide they're finished. If `FollowPlayer` doesn't need to be a coroutine (if it really should run every frame), that part could be changed to `FollowPlayer(); yield return null`.

Comment: My edit should have said: Every single frame, you're starting a `MoveAround` function. Since they're coroutines and take more than one frame to finish their action, you have a whole lot of `MoveAround`s running at the same time! Most likely, you actually want just one. That's what my code does--starts one, waits for it, then starts another.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. Im trying to make it works but it seems impossible... Im gonna stick with what you have told me and see what I can do with it. thanks again :D

Comment: You're welcome. I suggest using a pen and paper--"First, the position is set. Once. Then, a check happens. If true, this happens and immediately returns. Otherwise, this happens, and waits/continues until..."

Comment: Im new to this and its kinda difficult to me to divide behaviours in small steps... This is an example of that could you private message me for some questions? Thanks again.

Comment: @MarcosCosta Due to differing time zones, if you ask me in around 9 hours, I'll be happy to chat.